# Implement pwelch in matlab

Tags: matlab

I try to implement pwelch function in matlab.

here is my code

```
len = 65536;

data = randn(1, len);

overlap = 0.5;

w           = 256;
num_w       = len / (w * overlap);
hamming_win = hamming(w)';
win_normal  = mean(hamming_win.^2);

Pxx_sum = zeros(1, w/2+1);
for i = 1:num_w
    if i == 1
        block = [zeros(1, w * (1-overlap)) data(1:w * overlap)] .* hamming_win;
    else
        block = data((1:w) + (i-2) * w * overlap) .* hamming_win;
    end

    block_fd      = fft(block);
    block_fd_half = block_fd(1:w/2+1);

    Pxx = (block_fd_half .* conj(block_fd_half)) / (w * win_normal);
    Pxx_sum = Pxx_sum + Pxx;
end

psd_avg = Pxx_sum / num_w;
figure, plot(psd_avg);
```

and compare with matlab `pwelch`

```
[psd_mat freq] = pwelch(data, w, 0.5*w);
figure, plot(psd_mat)
```

[image: compare these results]

It seems there are a mismatch gain here.
If I replace my last two lines with

```
psd_avg = Pxx_sum / num_w * 0.318;  % <-----------
figure, plot(psd_avg);
```

[image: compare with new result]

I want to know

1. Where do I miss the 0.318 gain? Do I miss something?
2. First freq bin and last freq bin have big different with matlab result, why?

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I suspect you are not missing just a number, but that the number is the result of some equation into the input data that you are missing. I do not know the maths myself to help.

Comment: Octave implements the same function (but open source), it might help. Like Ander I have no clue of the math behind this function, so I won't attempt to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on Ander and Daniel's comment.

I review my code and compare with Octave's pwelch.

Here is what I found.

I remove `block_fd_half` like this

```
for i = 1:num_w

    ...

    block_fd  = fft(block);

    Pxx     = (block_fd .* conj(block_fd)) / (w * win_normal);
    Pxx_sum = Pxx_sum + Pxx;
end
```

and before plot the result

convert psd result from two sides to one side

```
psd_avg          = Pxx_sum / num_w;
psd_avg_one_side = psd_avg(1:w/2+1) + [0, psd_avg(w:-1:w/2+2) ,0];

figure, plot(psd_avg_one_side);
```

This is why my old result has a big difference in the first freq bin and last freq bin.

After these modified, my new result and octave result are exactly the same.

But, My new result also has a `(2*pi)` gain mismatch which compares with Matlab result.

I think this may be a normalizing factor to normalize sampling frequency?

Comment: this 2*pi is because of default fs = 2*pi, that is meaning pwelch(data, w) == pwelch(data, w, [], [], 2*pi)